# WPF - Attaching a custom property to a slider

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, dependency-properties, attached-properties

In my project, I am currently creating a slider in my code-behind the view and this slider has an event for when it's value changes. The place where the slider is created also has a custom object that is required for this project.

I wanted to have this custom object used as a property of the slider (similar to say `TicksProperty` within `Slider`), so that this could be passed through the `object sender` parameter of my `Slider_ValueChanged` event that I've created. The reason for this was so that I could execute an existing command from another class (my `ViewModel`) which uses this custom object as a parameter, everytime the value property changed.

However, I was aware that there was no way of adding a property to an existing WPF control so I decided to try an create a `CustomSlider` class that inherits from `Slider`, where it has this `CustomObject` as a `DependencyProperty`. I have tried looking at some examples and created the following below:

### CustomSlider Class

```
public class CustomSlider : Slider
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomObjectProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "CustomObject",
        typeof(CustomObject),
        typeof(CustomSlider),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null)
    );

    public CustomObject GetCustomObject(UIElement element)
    {
        return element.GetValue(CustomObjectProperty) as CustomObject;
    }

    public static void SetCustomObject(UIElement element, CustomObject value)
    {
        element.SetValue(CustomObjectProperty, value);
    }
}
```

### Code-Behind View

```
else if ()
{
    Binding sliderBinding = this.CustomBinding(customObject);
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(customObject.VarElement, CustomSlider.ValueProperty, sliderBinding);

    var tempSlider = customObject.VarElement as CustomSlider;

    ///How would I call the property here?

    tempSlider.ValueChanged += this.Slider_ValueChanged;
}

private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double>e)
{
    var tempSlider = sender as CustomSlider;

    ///command stuff called here
}
```

Any help on this topic would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are just passing around an arbitrary object, you could also use the  [Tag property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused the concepts of attached properties and derived controls. In a derived control, you would use a normal dependency property, not an attached property, like this:

```
public class CustomSlider : Slider
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomObjectProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "CustomObject",
            typeof(CustomObject),
            typeof(CustomSlider),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public CustomObject CustomObject
    {
        get { return (CustomObject)GetValue(CustomObjectProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CustomObjectProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Please note that you might also need to register a PropertyChangedCallback with the property metadata, to get notified when the property value changes. The callback would look like this:

```
private static void CustomObjectPropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CustomSlider customSlider = (CustomSlider)obj;
    ...
}
```

---

Now you could simply set your property like this:

```
var tempSlider = (CustomSlider)customObject.VarElement;
tempSlider.CustomObject = customObject;
```

or you could set a binding like this:

```
tempSlider.SetBinding(CustomSlider.CustomObjectProperty, sliderBinding);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

When creating the `PropertyChangedCallback` to register, should the custom slider be passed as the dependency object e.g.
    `public static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomSlider customSlider = (CustomSlider)obj;
    }`

Not too sure what else to do with this callback.

Comment: Exactly, you just have to cast the `obj` parameter to `CustomSlider`, the you can access the CustomSlider instance on which the property changes, e.g. call an instance method.

Comment: Another issue is casting between the `UIElement` to the `CustomSlider` type, used for `tempSlider`. This doesn't seem to work for some reason. Any idea on this, just out of curiosity?

Comment: Which UIElement? I don't see any in your question.

Comment: `VarElement` is of type `UIElement`.

Comment: No idea, as you haven't show the relevant code. If you had assigned VarElement to an instance of CustomSlider, the cast will work. Otherwise it will fail.